# How do I get specific values from a collection map

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a bot using DiscordJS here. 
I am currently trying to display user details. When I get the details, I'm not sure how to fetch specific details.

So I'm getting a user by doing

```
const user = await utils.findUser(message, args[0]);
```

Now here I get a user based on whatever the user entered in args. 
The user variable looks something like this:

```
Collection [Map] {
'211975876747853825' => GuildMember {
guild: Guild {
  members: [GuildMemberManager],   
  channels: [GuildChannelManager], 
  roles: [RoleManager],
  presences: [PresenceManager],    
  voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
  deleted: false,
  available: true,
  shardID: 0,
  name: 'Elchea Kingdom',
  icon: 'cd8156aed6c8ebc482df2252936afcee',
  splash: null,
  region: 'eu-west',
  large: false,
  features: [],
  applicationID: null,
  afkTimeout: 300,
  embedEnabled: undefined,
  premiumTier: 0,
  premiumSubscriptionCount: null,
  verificationLevel: 'MEDIUM',
  explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
  mfaLevel: 0,
  defaultMessageNotifications: 'MENTIONS',
  systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
  vanityURLCode: null,
  description: null,
  banner: null,
  rulesChannelID: null,
  publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
  ownerID: '211975876747853825',
  emojis: [GuildEmojiManager]
},
user: User {
  bot: false,
  discriminator: '0006',
  avatar: '5ebd62928be9bd413a2b5f6e638587ea',
  lastMessageID: null,
  lastMessageChannelID: null,
  flags: [UserFlags]
},
premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
deleted: false,
_roles: [
  '600421802702929920',
  '600737807664939008',
  '603343858549391360',
  '600425094598361091',
  '600422841279578118',
  '603314411243044875',
  '617699524474830859',
  '603316305495326740',
  '617505016328224790',
  '617449137767710743'
]
}
}
```

Now let's say I want to get get the Guild name which is "Elchea Kingdom". How could I do that? I have tried using Map.prototype.values() and iterate with it, but it doesn't work. I get an undefined value. I've tried doing stupid things such as user[0] and user.Guild to get guild information. But I always keep getting undefined value. What am I doing wrong, could you please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection

You should call the variable users and then get member by `.first()`

```js
const users = await utils.findUser(message, args[0]);
const member = users.first();
const user = member.user;
```

Which library are you using for the variable `utils` btw?

Comment: Thank you Karizma. That worked like a charm! <3
And utils is my custom script called Utility.js. Just a quick script to help me use re-usable code.  The findUser method is this:
module.exports.findUser = async (message, name) => {
 const member = await message.guild.members.fetch({ query: name, limit: 1 });
 return member;
};